# List all categories and count number of posts within (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, categories

I've written this function which nearly works:

```
function all_animals() {
    $categories = get_categories(array(
        'echo'             => 0,
        'hide_empty'       => 0,
        'taxonomy'         => 'species',
        'hierarchical'     => 1,
        'show_count'       => 0,
        'depth'            => 0
    )); ?>

    <ul>

    <?php ob_start();

    foreach ($categories as $cat) {

        $cat_args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'post_type'         => 'animal',
            'showposts'         => -1,
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'cat'               => $cat->cat_ID
        );
        $the_animals = new WP_Query($cat_args);
        $animal_count = $the_animals->post_count;
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->cat_ID ); ?>">
                <?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>
                <span class="count"><?php echo $animal_count; ?></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php 
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    $animal_list = ob_get_clean();
    return $animal_list;
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

...and then I use it on a page template like this:

```
echo all_animals();
```

**The problem:** The only thing not working is the `$animal_count` which always returns a 0.

I have also tried this...

```
global $wp_query; 
$animal_count = $wp_query->found_posts;
```

...but that made no difference.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
get_category('ID')->category_count
```

Here 'ID is category id

Comment: you can the category by name '<?php echo get_category(get_cat_ID('category name', 'betacoders'))->category_count; ?>'

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easier than I thought:

```
$animal_count = $the_animals->count;
```